# Do I need a specific websockets server to use websockets and "how"?

Tags: nginx, websocket, ubuntu-12.04, server-sent-events

I am currently running a nginx server with php5 installed (and it is now running 98.2% of its boot) to serve an web application I've been developing. In my programming career I'm used to using **server-sent events** but in this specific project I'd benefit more from websockets although I'm not at all understanding the basic procedures of setup, its relation with databases like mysql and how to stream data/send data despite the number of tutorials I come across. Having no proper implement of websockets doesn't allow me to understand it aswell. What I'd like to know is if I need to have a specific websockets server for this and how can I learn its setup "against" my already functioning server. I don't mind hyperlinks as answers but I really would like to understand this from its basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx proxying to websocket server (yes, there is another server than nginx).

Good examples from first hands:

http://nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html